# No target found - Phonegap Build Weinre debugging (iOS device from Windows laptop)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, weinre

I tested the Phonegap Build debug function but it is not working for me.

### What I Tried:

1) Checked the following build options in PGB:

Enable debugging, Enable Hydration and Private application.

2) Added the following line to the code:

```
<script src="http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#93281943klasd"></script>
```

3) Commited, pushed the changes with success.

4) Pulled the latest changes, rebuild the app and re-installed.

5) Run app.

6) Opened the URL: "https://debug1.phonegap.com/client/#93281943klasd" to check if Weinre has found a target.

But..... no target is found.

### Notes:

- I use Windows 8
- I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 7
- Using Phonegap Build, not Phonegap CLI
- Also tried the "debug"-button at the app page in Phonegap Build, but that's not working either

Comment: I have never gotten Phonegap Build to work with their online version of Weinre..  Never a target found.

Comment: I've got it both working on Android and iOS devices. The annoying thing is that both "debugging" and "hydration" enabled with Phonegap Build doesn't seem to work. Since they still didn't fix this issue, the development environment with PGB is in my opinion exhausting and far from efficiënt. If you consider creating hybrid apps, then only an Apple-device suits your needs to be fully dynamic on building cross-platform. Every development method with Windows devices lacks efficiency, debugging possibilities or both.

Comment: I installed Weinre on my server and i run it through ngrok.io so it works with https://  .. this works for me.